# how to sort mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to sort mysql by latest logged in but I have to resort it everytime i log in, how do I sort and save the latest login?

Comment: Why do you need to physically resort the table? Would a `SELECT blah FROM table ORDER BY name` be sufficient?

Comment: @Melissa Because i want to sort it latest logged in...

Comment: I need to understand what's the problem to try to help you . you can select them sorted ? ...

Comment: @Lukus you can achieve that by issuing a SELECT query against the table in question and sorting the result in an ORDER BY clause. Doing a ALTER TABLE ORDER BY query is an intensive option.

Comment: @Melissa SELECT ??? FROM TABLE `user` ORDER BY `login` DESC what do i put in ???

Comment: I posted a query below as an answer - it may be of use to you.

Comment: @Melissa I actually want to sort the whole table from latest login to last...

Comment: @lukus to do that just remove the `LIMIT 1` from the query.

Comment: @Melissa its not a query I want to run. When I log in and browse the records I want the latest login first. this only runs a query..

Comment: Ok. The idea was to offer you an alternative to physically sorting a table. As you saw in the answers below, it is not a good idea. You could either keep doing that, use a query to get the latest data, or set up a view to automatically execute the query and update your system/page/whatever to look at the view rather than the actual table. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably keep the values stored in MySQL in alphabetical order. The best you can do is use the `ORDER BY` clause in your `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you sort things when you select by adding an "ORDER BY" clause. Why do you care what order they are actually stored in the table?

If you really care, I guess you could do an INSERT...SELECT to copy it to a new table while sorting the column, but whenever you add a new record, it will end up at the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

SQL doesn't work that way. It's not like a spreadsheet where the rows are meant to be read "as-is" and you can put them in a certain meaningful order. Nothing you do ever changes the order that SQL stores the rows in. SQL gives you data through queries, and the query tells it which rows you want to see, in what order.

So, you have to reuse the "order by" clause every time you want to see your data in a certain order. However, you shouldn't need to manually query SQL a lot. If you're writing any kind of script or application to work with it, you'll just write the query once and re-run it each time you want the data.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last login from your user table, you could use a query like

```
 SELECT user_name, login_datetime
 FROM   user_table 
 ORDER BY login_datetime DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

Assuming that `user_name` is the field you are looking for and `login_datetime` is a timestamp you can order on. `LIMIT 1` will show only the top most result and can be changed depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL's InnoDB engine, your rows are physically ordered according to the primary key. So, if the primary key is on the `login` column, then the rows will stay in physical order by the values in `login`.

The requirement of a primary key is that each value must be unique and NULL is not allowed. So, you may consider making the `login` column your primary key. If `login` were a datetime column, then the latest login datetime value would always be at the end of the table.

Many people make an auto-increment integer column their primary key. In this case, the last record to be inserted would always be at the end of the table.

You must know the value of having your rows in physical order (by a particular column) for certain circumstances, otherwise you wouldn't be asking.

For example, doing the following `SELECT` returns the rows in physical order (same as primary key) without having to specify a column to order the results by, and without forcing MySQL to later order the result set:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
```

However, if you need to order the results other than by the primary key, then you should utilize the `ORDER BY` clause. For example, if the rows were physically ordered by the column `name`, but you want the results returned in order by `login`, you would issue the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
ORDER BY login ASC
```

The above query asks MySQL to order the rows according to the specified column. You specify `ASC` in the `ORDER BY` clause to order the values in ascending order, and `DESC` to order them in descending order.